# embedded linux, initramfs with buildroot

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, boot, buildroot, initrd

in my embedded system I'd like to use initramfs to perform some special operation.
Someone managed to make initramfs work?
I'm using buildroot 2016.2, the kernel is from my provider and we are at 3.0.x. I've enabled initramfs, so I just have to pass the path to my cpio.
At the moment getty is not working.

```
can't opegetty: can't opegetty: can't opegetty:
```

and hang forever.

Any idea?could be a toolchain problem?

I have used the tag initrd because there is not "initramfs"

Comment: *"Someone managed to make initramfs work?"* -- Yes, many tiimes, with and w/o Buildroot.  *"so I just have to pass the path to my cpio"* -- You should not have to do that if you're using Buildroot for kernel and rootfs.  Buildroot has an extra-pass build mechanism exclusively for initramfs.  Simply reporting only the error message without any previous context is not helpful.

Comment: can you provide kernel bootup log?

Comment: This sounds like you're missing a /init script that mounts /dev and redirects I/O to /dev/console. If you use buildroot's BR2_TARGET_ROOTFS_CPIO (or BR2_TARGET_ROOTFS_INITRAMFS), you'll get this /init script for free.

Comment: Thank you to you all. I think it was a kernell headers problem plus some garbage from multiple build in the same folder. I downloaded again the whole buildroot, and I choose the kernel headers closer to my actual kernel (I'm using an SDK of a particular SOC). Now it works. Could you please confirm that this architecture do not touch the NAND? always live and work in the RAM? Thanks